# Аутентификация в android-приложении

Tags: java, android, spring

Есть web-приложение с аутентификацией пользователей по логину и паролю на java со spring, hibernate. Хочу сделать android-приложение с аутентификацией пользователей. Какой лучше способ использовать? Стоит ли пробовать прикручивать spring-android с oauth2?

Comment: а почему не сделать так же - по логину и паролю? Вы же передаете их в случае *не андроид прилодения* каким-то образом на сервер? По HTTP POST? Почему так же не сделать и на Android?

Comment: в приложении прикручен spring-security, где указана страница авторизации, прописаны переменные, чтобы spring видел их итд. А как такую же штуку прикрутить к android???